# Rails why autocomplete association is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, associations

I have a association between jobs and companies and i want to implement a autocomplete features 
in my jobs.js.coffe file i have this code

```
jQuery ->
  $('#job_company_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#job_company_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

and this is my Job form view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: companies_path} %>
</div> 
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :job_title, "Intitulé du poste", class: "jobs-newtitles" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :job_title, class: "form-control form-newjob"  %>
</div>
```

this is my job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :job_title, use: :slugged


      def company_name
        company.try(:name)
      end

      def company_name=(name)
        self.company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
      end

end
```

I have also added this to my company controller

```
  def autocomplete
    @companies = Company.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @companies.map(&:name) }
    end
  end
```

and this is my routes

```
  concern :autocompletable do
    get 'autocomplete', on: :collection
  end

resources :companies, concerns: :autocompletable
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified autocomplete url "companies_path", while your autocomplete action is 'autocomplete'.

Check the correct autocomplete path, with this inspection:

```
  $ rake routes | grep autocomplete
```

I assumes, you need modify autocomplete_source to something like this:

```
  <%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: companies_autocomplete_path} %>
```